# Ansible: appending to a list conditionally

Tags: ansible

I'm quite new to Ansible, so please be patient. I'm trying to come up with an elegant way to populate a list.  Some of the items should be in the list unconditionally, for example, item1. Some of them would be added to the list if "when" conditions are met. So far I got this and it is not working, I assume it just overrides item1 with item2 and 3. Also, it starts looking ugly the more items you add. Has anyone had experience with populating ansible lists conditionally?

```
 - name: Add items to list
      set_fact:
        items_list: ["item1"]
      with_items: 
        - item2
          when:
           - condition1 is defined
           - condition3 is defined
        - item3
          when:
          - condition 4 is defined
```

Comment: Only variables can be tested as [defined](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#defined). Is this really what you want? Testing the existence of variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    - set_fact:
        items_list: "{{ items_list | default(['item1']) + [item] }}"
      loop:
        - "{{ (True and True) | ternary('item2', None) }}"
        - "{{ (True) | ternary('item3', None) }}"
      when: item
    - debug: var=items_list
```

or

```
     - set_fact:
         items_list: "{{ items_list | default(['item1']) + [item] }}"
       loop:
         - "item2"
         - "item3"
       when: >-
         (item == "item2" and True and True) or
         (item == "item3" and True)
     - debug: var=items_list
```

Answer (score 0):

The use-case is adding an item to a list if some variables are [defined](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#defined). The best structure is a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
    d1:
      item1:
        l: []
      item2:
        l: [condition1, condition3]
      item3:
        l: [condition4]
```

If the variable *condition4* is defined but others are not the task below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        items_list: "{{ items_list|default([]) + [item.key] }}"
      loop: "{{ d1|dict2items }}"
      when: _vals|from_yaml is all
      vars:
        _vals: |
          [
          {% for i in  item.value.l %}
          {{ vars[i] is defined }},
          {% endfor %}
          ]
```

gives

```yaml
  items_list:
  - item1
  - item3
```

Comment: What is `is all`?